# Getting value from database in blade template in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Here I want to get value from database. I am using this in layout and I don't want to use controller for getting value. It does not show anything. How can I fix it? Thank in advance

**info.blade.php**

```
{{$data = \App\visitor::where('flag',1)->get()}}

    @foreach ($data as $val)
       Name  {{ $val->v_name }} <br>
       Mobile  {{ $val->v_mobile }}
     @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though its not a good idea to not use controller you can do like

```
@php
    $data = \App\visitor::where('flag',1)->get()
@endphp
```

Comment: I know. But I want to show value in layout.blade.php

Comment: you need to put this code inside layout.blade.php then

Comment: Ok thanks 
 @foreach($data as $val)
     {{ $val ->v_name}}
@endforeach

Comment: Sorry . it runes properly

Comment: I am trying with one thing with long time....... I will so happy if u suggest anything regarding  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48728539/getting-error-to-convert-and-store-base64-encoding-to-an-image-in-laravel-5-4